# Random audio player integrated with mute button

Tags: html5-audio

Forgive my ignorance.

I am on the steep end of the learning curve for js (and I am 61 years old so the synapses are not firing like they used to).

I have used this code provided by an expert on this site to play a random selection from a list of audio files:

```
// JavaScript Document


var collection=[];// final collection of sounds to play
var loadedIndex=0;// horrible way of forcing a load of audio sounds

// remap audios to a buffered collection
function init(audios) {
  for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    collection.push(audio);
    buffer(audio);
  }
}

// did I mention it's a horrible way to buffer?
function buffer(audio) {
  if(audio.readyState==4)return loaded();
  setTimeout(function(){buffer(audio)},100);
}

// check if we're leady to dj this
function loaded() {
  loadedIndex++;
  if(collection.length==loadedIndex)playLooped();
}

// play and loop after finished
function playLooped() {
  var audio=Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length));
  audio=collection[audio];
  audio.play();
  setTimeout(playLooped,audio.duration*1000);
}

// the songs to be played!
init([
  'audio/song1.mp3', 'audio/song2.mp3', 'audio/song3.mp3', 'audio/song4.mp3', 'audio/song5.mp3'
]);
```

And I have used this code in a separate trial to add a mute button for a single audio file to avoid annoying visitors to the site if they are not hip to the music:

```
// JavaScript Document
$("audio").prop('muted', false);

$(".mute-audio").click(function () {
    if ($("audio").prop('muted')) {
        $("audio").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).addClass('unmute-audio');

    } else {
        $("audio").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).removeClass('unmute-audio');
    }
    console.log($("audio").prop('muted'))
});
```

What I cannot figure out how to accomplish is integrating the MUTE function with the RANDOM AUDIO PLAY function.

Thanks to anyone willing to give me a little guidance!

Comment: Is the mute function not targeting all audio objects though? I would think that it would work given that the function doesn't target a specific audio object

Comment: Thanks Jonathan -that's what I thought too - but I am missing something because I have not been able to make it work like that - the mute code targets the audio element delineated in the html just fine but has no impact on the audio pulled from a  separate directory by the js that initiates the random selection and play. It's not clear to me why the mute routine does not "see" those audio elements. Thanks for the response!